# 'Problem' and 'help' titles in off-topic questions of new users coming from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, stackoverflow, asking-questions

I recently learned that some off-topic questions seem to be posted at Programmers with sole purpose to circumvent ['problem'](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7205/31260) and ['help'](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22863090#22863090) title block at Stack Overflow.

Can we do something to save these askers frustration and disappointment when their off-topic questions get voted down and close? Absence of the block probably makes them expect warmer welcome over here.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ZyG.png]

Related:

- [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/lets-help-askers-who-are-trying-to-circumvent-question-block-at-stack-overflow)
- [Is it time to tighten up the quality filter at Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5843/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-quality-filter-at-programmers?lq=1)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. +1

Comment: it looks like magic, but for _over ten days_ since I posted this, I have seen no 'problem' questions anymore. I re-tested the title block and it doesn't look like things changed: it's there at SO and absent at Programmers, just like it was when I posted (though I had no way to test maybe such block was introduced for low rep users over here)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that this doesn't happen frequent enough to warrant changes to the system, one approach that comes to mind is to flag these cases for moderator attention.

Flag message explaining the issue could refer this very question, in order to make it easier for moderator to find more details, eg like as follows:

`please take a look - this off-topic question appears to be posted with sole purpose to circumvent 'problem' title block at Stack Overflow (related meta discussion: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7221)`

<sub>Because, really, what's the point of wasting [precious close votes](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6507/31260) on an issue essentially caused by some kind of a system "leak".</sub>

---

Note, per discussion in later related question, some moderators are *not* positive about flags like that: [Is it okay to flag for moderator intervention attempts to circumvent question block at other site?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7328/31260)

On another note, you may also stumble upon [an earlier post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6508/31260) that recommends this approach...

> if you see someone that is very likely unable to ask questions on one site bringing the same poor quality here - flag it

...but you better keep in mind that above guidance is *not* universally accepted. At least not currently.